# How to get the current zoom of the map [getZoom()] in react-google-maps?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I want to get the current zoom level of my map in react-google-maps like we do in simple google map api with the getZoom() function. How to do this in react-google-maps ?

I have looked few answers but none of them are working for me.

```
import React from "react"
import {
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  withGoogleMap,
  withScriptjs,
} from "react-google-maps"


const Map = () => {
  return (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={15}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: lat, lng: lng }}
    >
      <Marker position={{ lat: lat, lng: lng }} />
    </GoogleMap>
  )
}

const WrappedMap = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map))

const Index = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <WrappedMap
        googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
        key=my_key&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places`}
        loadingElement={<Loading />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Index
```

How can I getZoom for the above shown example.

Comment: What specifically have you tried so far and how have the failed? That can help with diagnosing where you're going wrong.

Comment: @ebbishop I am trying to follow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581791/react-ts-react-google-maps-property-getzoom-does-not-exist-on-type-refob) .But  I am not using typescript, I am using jsx and a simple functional component. I will be happy if there is any other way by which I can access the current zoom of map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GoogleMap` component from `react-google-maps` exposes `onZoomChanged` method which corresponds to native Google Map `zoom_changed` event and is triggered once the map's zoom level changes

Here is an example how to retrieve current zoom in `WrappedMap` component:

```
const Map = ({center,zoom}) => {

  function handleZoomChanged(){
    console.log(this.getZoom()) //this refers to Google Map instance
  }


  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={zoom} defaultCenter={center} onZoomChanged={handleZoomChanged} >
      <Marker position={center} />
    </GoogleMap>
  );
};
```

Another option would be to pass current zoom from a child component via `onZoomChanged`  prop:

```
const Map = ({ center, zoom, onZoomChanged }) => {
  function handleZoomChanged() {
    onZoomChanged(this.getZoom()); //current zoom
  }

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={zoom}
      defaultCenter={center}
      onZoomChanged={handleZoomChanged}
    >
      <Marker position={center} />
    </GoogleMap>
  );
};
```

and then introduce `currentZoom` state to store current zoom level in parent component:

```
const App = () => {

  const [currentZoom, setCurrentZoom] = useState(5);//default

  //print current Map zoom on button click
  function handleClick() {
    console.log(currentZoom);
  }

  function handleZoomChanged(newZoom) {
    setCurrentZoom(newZoom);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Get Zoom</button>
      <Map
        googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDurZQBXjtSzKeieXwtFeGe-jhZu-HEGQU"
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        center={{ lat: -40.4338962, lng: 166.3297536 }}
        zoom={currentZoom}
        onZoomChanged={handleZoomChanged}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Here is a demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-e17zmx)

Answer (score 5):

react-google-maps/api

Copy the basic template from below make sure to give values to **lat**, **lng**, and **apiKey**

The **GoogleMap** component from "@react-google-maps/api" takes a prop **onLoad** which is of type function.
This **onLoad** function takes a default parameter which is the current instance of the **map**.

I am using react hooks here to set the state in my functional component you can also use the class based component. Just setState of the current instance of map.

```
import React from "react"
import { GoogleMap, LoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api"

const apikey = "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"

// lat and lng are float numbers not string
const lat = lat_value
const lng = lng_value

const Map = props => {
  const [map, setMap] = React.useState(null)
  return (
    <LoadScript id="script-loader" googleMapsApiKey={apikey}>
      <GoogleMap
        // set the state with the current instance of map.
        onLoad={map => {
          setMap(map)
        }}
        mapContainerStyle={{
          height: "400px",
          width: "800px",
        }}
        zoom={16}
        center={{
          lat: lat,
          lng: lng,
        }}
        id="example-map"
        // here onZoomChanged we are accessing the current zoom value from our map
        //instance which is stored in the state
        onZoomChanged={() => {
          console.log(map.getZoom())
        }}
      >
        ...Your map components
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  )
}

export default Map
```

That should log the current zoom value in the console as soon as you change the zoom of your map.